# Can I use AWS DataPipeline to merge dynamoDBs and edit items before each put?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a dynamo table that has depreciated and I need to merge it into another table. The schema for the two tables are slightly different, and so I need to do some minor work on each item before I can put items into the surviving table.

Now, I know that I could always create a lambda that writes a batch of these records into a kinesis stream that's watched by another lambda that could put the records in the surviving table, but this seems kludgy to me. DataPipeline seems like a better solution but I'm not sure if I can alter items before they are moved to the new table. Same with EMR.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Data pipeline , in its import/export template uses DynamoDB connector's    Import/Export Tool to copy contents from source to destination. See https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector

The tool simply launches the Hadoop implementation to run mappers/Reducers to do your job. However, the tool doesn't have enough control to alter items nor have a DynamoDB -> DynamoDB ETL.

However, as all EMR clusters come with emr-dynamodb-connector libraries  you can use either HIVE / SPARK to write your own DDL's and DML's to copy DynamoDB -> DynamoDB(same AWS region). If you write the DML's correct, you might even copy data between two DynamoDB tables with different schema's using your own clauses. You can later automate those scripts to run on EMR resource created by Data-pipeline on a schedule.

The presudo code for hql to copy from one table to another can be as simple as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb_table (`ID` STRING,`DateTime` STRING)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "ddb-table-1", "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "ID:ID,DateTime:DateTime");

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dynamodb_table2 (`ID` STRING,`DateTime` STRING)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler' 
TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = "ddb-table-2", "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "ID:ID,DateTime:DateTime");

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE  dynamodb_table SELECT * FROM dynamodb_table2;
```

Hive DDL's and DML syntax's can be found here : 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML

Some examples on using DynamoDB storage handler on EMR :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.html